# How do I count not equal to wildcard characters in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, countif

Using `COUNTIF(range,"<>")` can I count non-empty cells and with `COUNTIF(range,"~?")` or `COUNTIF(range,"~*")` can I calculate the number of cells matching a wildcard character, but can I do it with one COUNTIF() ?

`COUNTIF(range,"<>~?")` does not work.

Comment: Kim, using ~before a wild-card character tells excel NOT to use the * or ? as a wildcard but to actually look for ? or *

Comment: @Charles: Why are you telling me what I already said in the question ?

Comment: Because to me your question says you want to count all cells that do NOT match the wildcard string rather than count all cells that do not contain the actual ? or * characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding here is that you want to count cells in a range that satisfy two conditions - 1) they are not blank, 2) they are not "?"

If you are using Excel 2007 or later try COUNTIFS (with an "S" on the end) with both conditions like this

`=COUNTIFS(range,"<>",range,"<>~?")`

or for earlier versions use SUMPRODUCT

`=SUMPRODUCT((range<>"")*(range<>"?"))`

[Note: you don't need ~ in the latter]

In Excel 2003 or earlier **range** can't be a whole column. You can use the same approach for *

Comment: Just added a tag for my version of excel. I have no blank cells, but its an excellent additional condition. As I already specified, COUNTIF() doesnt work properly when searching for cells `not` equal to `?`

Comment: @Kim I'm not clear, then, does that COUNTIFS formula do what you want? How does COUNTIF not work properly? If I use =COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>~?") it does what I expect, it gives me a count of cells that are not literally ? (even blanks).

Comment: My mistake. Turned out I did have blank cells, which is why my COUNTIF() didnt give the result I was expecting. I used `IF(cell="?",1,0)` in a helper column for my cells and then summed it, but with this blank cells gave `0` which skewed the total number. Using `COUNTIFS()` to exclude blank cells fixes my issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Using COUNTIF(range,"<>") can I count non-empty cells

You can use COUNTA() to Count Non Empty Cells.

```
=COUNTA(A1:A10)
```

If you still want to use COUNTIF() then yes, you can use it like

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>")
```

You can use wildcards to count for cells which have specific words like this

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Kim*")   '<~~ Starts with "Kim"
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*Kim*")  '<~~ Contains "Kim"
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*Kim")   '<~~ Ends with "Kim"
```

To count Not Equal to With WildCards, you can use this

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>Kim*")   '<~~ Doesn't Start with "Kim"
```

Comment: @ Invisible Sniper: would definitely love to know the reason for the downvote :)

Comment: You are describing how to use `COUNTA` and `COUNTIF` in a general way. The office help is sufficient to get that information. I was looking for a reason why my formula to count cells with a non-wildcard character gave a different result than expected.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Kim. Seems like I misunderstood your question... :)

Comment: @Kim: no, the office help is not sufficient. The `COUNTIFS` help page doesn't bother to mention the `<>` operator.

Comment: +1 for `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>Kim*")   '<~~ Doesn't Start with "Kim"`

Answer (score 0):

this may have been just fixed in Excel 2010:
=COUNTIF(H:H,"<>~?") correctly counts only non-? values in column H
(so ? and '? reduce the count, but quoted "?", A, etc all don't)